# Elasticsearch indexing process killed

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, virtual-machine

Elasticseach indexing process gets killed by oom after 200000 documents. I did not find related or anything useful in logs.

I'm using a Ubuntu VM, 5GB ram, two 3.0GH cores.

I tried to disable the swap. Read that ES works poorly when swap is enabled, but no luck. Am I missing some configuration?

/etc/default/elasticsearch

ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g

MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535

MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited

Comment: We had same problem, in our scenario the root cause  was unclosed db connections.Try increasing pool size if you are using hibernate or something like this

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? I don't have much experience with ES.

Comment: Its not regarding ES? Its about data fetching. Are you fetching data from database

Comment: Are you using a bulk request to populate your index?  If so, how many requests are you sending?  Where is your data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use ES bulk API? If so, you may check the bulk size. According to the document [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)：

> There is no "correct" number of actions to perform in a single bulk request. Experiment with different settings to find the optimal size for your particular workload. Note that Elasticsearch limits the maximum size of a HTTP request to 100mb by default so clients must ensure that no request exceeds this size.